# couldn't download intellicode model. please check your network connectivity or firewall settings in vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellicode

I have downloaded JDK, java extension pack and code runner.
When I run my program it says " couldn't download intellicode model. please check your network connectivity or firewall settings ".

ANY SOLUTION!

Comment: Have you check your network connectivity and firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of VS Code, and turn on *network proxy support*.

> [image]
>
> Setting it to `override` should work best for most setups, try `on` for comparison when that doesn't work well

If the problem persists, please refer to these two GitHub issues.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/4

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/49#issuecomment-455082089

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

1. setting proxy.

   {"http.proxySupport": "override",
   "http.proxy": "socks5://127.0.0.1:xxxx"}
2. setting path, fix "EROFS: read-only file system, open 'models.json', (Error)".

   {"vsintellicode.modelDownloadPath": "/Users/xxxx/.vscode/vsintellicodemodels"}